# apt-get unusable because of virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, virtuoso

On our server we have Virtuoso 6.1 installed but somehow Ubuntu tries to install Virtuoso 7 as well (or maybe someone tried to install it). In any case, now apt-get is not usable at all and proposes to be fixed with `apt-get -f install` which fails (see at the bottom).

Output of `uname -a`:
`Linux servername 3.2.0-45-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:12:06 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Output:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblcms1 libcupsimage2 libvirtodbc0 libmagickcore4 linux-headers-3.2.0-51 libjbig2dec0 liblcms2-2 libmagickwand4 libgs9-common virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin liblqr-1-0
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common imagemagick-common libijs-0.35 cmap-adobe-japan1 linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic gs-cjk-resource libgs9 ghostscript linux-headers-3.2.0-51-generic
  libpaper-utils gsfonts libpaper1 virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 201548 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common (from .../virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common_7.0.1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common_7.0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/INIFILE.1.gz', which is also in package virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common 6.1.4+dfsg1-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common_7.0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Uninstalling Virtuoso 7 doesn't work also.

```
# apt-get remove virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvirtodbc0 : Depends: virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common (= 7.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Question for askubuntu.com. Try `aptitude --full-resolver remove virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common` and check different solutions it will offer, maybe one of them will be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 2):

THis is not the right place for this kind of question, but anyway:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvirtodbc0 : Depends: virtuoso-opensource-7.0-common (= 7.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Just do `sudo apt-get remove libvirtodbc0`, and apt-get should work again.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you obtain the Virtuoso 7 debian packages from as I didn't think Debian/Ubuntu have an official Virtuoso 7 set of packages yet, or did you build them yourself or obtain from some other source ?

Comment: I think the package came from the LOD2 Stack Virtuoso 7 debian package. So the conflict may have been caused by having both the Ubuntu Virtuoso 6 and the LOD 2 Stack Virtuoso 7 installed at the same time.